# Ubuntu not booting when a PCIe network interface card (NIC) is installed

Tags: boot

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS does not boot when I install a PCIe Network Interface Card (NIC), Xilinx X2522-25G, on my machine. If I remove the NIC, then the PC again boots properly.

I got this issue previously on another PC (also having 18.04 LTS). But other two other PCs have had no issues with NICs until today. I confronted the issue today with the two PCs when I turned on them after leaving them off for a week.

When turned on, the motherboard splash (logo) is shown (with a sentence 'press F2 or DEL to enter UEFI ...'), turns to black screen, and then nothing happens. In normal operation, the motherboard splash and Ubuntu logo should be popped up after the screen is turned black but, when the NIC is installed, nothing happens. Again, I turn off the machine by pressing the power button, remove the NIC, then the PC boots properly.

Is there any clue for this issue? or how can I figure out the problem? Can I obtain a log file for the booting process and preserve it after I conduct the power-button-reboot?

Comment: Most probably this is a hardware issue and not an Ubuntu issue. At this point  in the boot-chain Ubuntu is not active. Maybe the NIC is incompatibe with your board or in best case some Bios settings need adjustment. In rare cases, replacing the Bios battery helps.

Comment: @Marco Thanks for the comment. But I wonder why this issue appears today while I had no issue for the one year. I suspected the NIC was broken but this error occurs with other NICs (same models X2522). Anyway, It seems that there's no way to figure out the issue as you mentioned that the Ubuntu is not active. Thank you!